# How create a type like AnyHashable in Swift?

Tags: swift, constructor, init

In Swift we have `AnyHashable` type erased wrapper which can be constructed from any hashable concrete type.
`var ah: AnyHashable {"..."/*hashable string type*/}`

But when I create a struct like below:

```
struct Demo{
    init(_ value: String){...}
}

var demo: Demo {"..."} // Cannot convert return expression of type 'String' to return type 'Demo'
```

Why? and how to create a type which can constructed from `String` ..

Answer (score 1):

You need to make your type conform to `ExpressibleByStringLiteral`

```
struct Demo: ExpressibleByStringLiteral {
    init(_ value: String) {
        //...
    }

    //Conform to ExpressibleByStringLiteral:
    init(stringLiteral value: String) {
        self.init(value)
    }
}
```

Now you can initialise it using strings

```
var demo: Demo {"..."}
var demo2: Demo = "demo"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But if I want type `P.init(QLiteral value: Q){}`, there's NO `ExpressibleByQLiteral`, how to do that?

Comment: well your question was about String so that is what I answered. But what you need to to is to create that protocol yourself containing that init method, then it is up to the conforming class to convert a Q to itself in `init(QLiteral:)`